# Pagination with many to many relationship in laravel

Tags: mysql, email, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I'm trying to set up Email system in laravel 4.2. I have two model Email and User with a many to many relationship between them. So far so good but now I just stuck with a problem while paginating send emails. I've been trying for 2 days but didn't accomplish the task yet.

```
    //User.php    Model
    public function emails()
    {   
        return $this->belongsToMany('Email', 'users_email', 'reciever_uid','email_id')->
         withPivot('sender_UID');
    }

    //Email.php  Model
    public function users()
    {   
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_email', 'email_id','reciever_id');
    }
```

I've tried to fetch the users_email pivot table data to get all the email ids of the current
authenticated user QueryBuilder.

```
    $user=Auth::Id();
    $user_data=DB::table('users_email')->
    join('users','users_email.reciever_uid','=','users.Id')->
    where('users_email.sender_uid','=',$user->Id)->orderby   
    ('users_email.email_id','desc')->get();

    foreach ($user_data as $data) {
    $id[]=$data->email_id;
   }
```

Now I have $id array and I want to fetch all the emails along with the f_name and l_name of the receiver to be displayed.
So far I've tried eager loading with some basic knowledge but couldn't get the
expected result. I've tried something this to paginate all the emails within
$id but getTotal returns only 2 even though the picture shown below specifies that the email with id=78 had sent 8 n more so I want to paginate via emails.
E.x prepage only 10 emails.

```
    $pagination=User::with(array('emails'=>function($query) use ($id){
        $query->WhereIn('users_email.email_id',$id);
    }))->paginate(10);
```

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Thank you

Pivot Table users_email

[image]

Comment: What you have done is pretty clear but I don't understand what you want to do. Get all the emails sent by a user, paginated ? Get all the users, paginated, and their emails sent eager loaded ? Get all the users with their n first emails sent ?

Comment: @Alexendre Butynski The problem is that the getTotal paginated number returns 2  which in this case I want to be 9 because the user 79 had sent 9 emails.
every thing is working fine except the pagination numbers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to write two different relationships :

```
//User.php
public function emailsReceived()
{   
    return $this->belongsToMany('Email', 'users_email', 'reciever_uid','email_id')->withPivot('sender_uid');
}
public function emailsSent()
{   
    return $this->belongsToMany('Email', 'users_email', 'sender_uid','email_id')->withPivot('reciever_uid');
}
```

And then you will be able to simply retrieve all the emails sent :

```
$user = Auth::user();
$emailsSentByUser = $user->emailsSent;
$paginatedEmailsSentByUser = $user->emailsSent()->paginate(10);
```

Note that when you let the brackets after the relation name, you are able to chain query builder methods.

Comment: Actually I was thinking for second relationship but then I thought that might be only single relationship works at a time...! Thanks

Comment: Worked for me too in Laravel 5.1!